# Find and remove duplicate words in lines in a file using python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I want to remove extra words that follow the first one in sequence separated by ";" on each line and return just one copy of that sequnce in a line:

Data:

```
XTY1;XTY3;XTY3;XTY3;XTY2;XTY1;XTY1;XTY1
XTY3;XTY4;XTY4;XTY3;XTY2;XTY7;XTY7;XTY1
XTY10;XTY3;XTY4;XTY2;XTY2;XTY11;XTY11;XTY1
```

Required output:

```
XTY1;XTY3;XTY2;XTY1
XTY3;XTY4;XTY3;XTY2;XTY7;XTY1
XTY10;XTY3;XTY4;XTY2;XTY11
```

My code is as follows:

```
for line in cluster3_urls:
    list_of_words = line.split(',')
for i in list_of_words:
    next_word = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(i) + 1]
    if list_of_words == next_word:
        list_of_words=list_of_words
        print list_of_words
```

Can someone please let me know why my code did not work?

Comment: Why are you splitting on `','` instead of `';'`?

Comment: what's the explanation for the last word in the example?

Comment: Apologies. I meant to split on ";"

Comment: There is nothing special about last words, but they have new line after them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things wrong with your code. Consider `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

input = 'XTYYY1;XTYYY3;XTYYY3;XTYYY3;XTYYY2;XTYYY1;XTYYY1;XTYYY1'

output = ';'.join([k for k, g in groupby(input.split(';'))])

# output: 'XTYYY1;XTYYY3;XTYYY2;XTYYY1'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time. Your solution worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are spiting based on commas instead of semicolon
try change the line to

```
list_of_words = line.split(';')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code right now is failing because you are splitting on the wrong delimiter. In addition, once you fix that, your code will additionally fail on `next_word = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(i) + 1]` when you reach the last word. The rest of your code just makes no sense, with your if statement comparing an array to an element of that array, then setting that arrow to itself (doing nothing). I recommend you completely rewrite your code.